# How to find/replace and ignore encoding

Tags: python, encoding, replace, utf-8, ascii

I would like to do in-place replacement of `ascii` strings into a list of files.

I initially tried `fileinput` but I got this awful message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encoder character u'\u026a'...
```

So I wrote this:

```
for f in ls_files(repo.tree()):
    copyfile(f, f + '.bak')
    with open(f, 'w') as dst:
        with open(f + '.bak') as src:            
            for line in src:
                newline = line.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
                for a, b in changes:
                    newline = newline.replace(a, b)                    
                dst.write(newline)
```

The issue appears with the `encode`/`decode` declarations.

If I put `dst_write(newline.encode('utf-8'))` I get no errors but all the accents are removed from the processed files. Without `encode('utf-8')` I get  errors on some files.

I really don't understand why I need to care about the encoding when I do replacement of `ascii`.

With a different approach using `binary` read I also get the same errors:

```
for f in ls_files(repo.tree()):
    copyfile(f, f + '.bak')
    print "Processing %s ..." % f,
    with open(f, 'wb') as dst:
        with open(f + '.bak', 'rb') as src:  
            content = src.read()           
            for a, b in changes:
                content = content.replace(a, b)                
            dst.write(content)
```

How can I just replace `ascii` content into my file without getting any issue as I can do it with `perl` or `sed`:

```
$ perl -pi -e s/foo/bar/g any_type_of_file
```

**EDIT**

It seems it work with

```
content = content.replace(bytes(a), bytes(b))
```

but... it's ugly...

Comment: where is changes defined?

Comment: @Ni. You can look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nowox/168fa2848c94206770960f29ca964dc4) for example

Comment: maybe a or b are unicode?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are not. They are filenames which are pure ascii (at least they should).